# Outlined mat-card

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am using Material Design Angular components.

I want to use mat-card component but to have it outlined, not raised. What is the proper way to do that? Is it done through some set of Material Angular directives or do I use Material Design classes?

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

You can flatten the mat-card by use of the elevation css classes/mixins:
https://material.angular.io/guide/elevation

This will remove the raised:

```html
<mat-card class="mat-elevation-z0">
...
<mat-card>
```

Then you can simply apply a custom class with a border style or add it to the mat-card in your component's css

```html
<mat-card class="mat-elevation-z0 outline">
...
<mat-card>
```

```css
.outline {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular Material card now provides an `appearance` property, which you can set to outlined like so:

```html
<mat-card appearance="outlined">
...
</mat-card>
```

This requires v15.